# Is Umbridge really related to Selwyn?

Tags: harry-potter

In HP7, Umbridge, with the locket, says that she is related to Selwyn with the "pure-blood chains."

Is this true?

Comment: I don't think there's a canon answer to this (unless I've missed or forgotten something from Pottermore or something), but I'd say there's a very good chance she's full of shit.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Umbridge is full of shit in many things also, so why would she not be in this? :P

Comment: @RikerW Exactly.

Comment: [Certainly related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/what-was-dolores-umbridges-blood-status?rq=1)

Comment: @Au101 I just spent five minutes going through that question looking for places that would show that Umbridge was “certainly related” to the Selwyns before I realised you meant _that question_ is certainly related to this one. <facepalm>

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oooops, sorry, I probably could have worded that a little bit more carefully

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If she is related to Selwyn, it certainly isn't in the way she claims.

From Pottermore by J.K. Rowling:

> "Dolores Jane Umbridge was the eldest child and only daughter of Orford Umbridge, a wizard, and Ellen Cracknell, a Muggle, who also had a Squib son. Dolores’s parents were unhappily married, and Dolores secretly despised both of them: Orford for his lack of ambition (he had never been promoted, and worked in the Department of Magical Maintenance at the Ministry of Magic), and her mother, Ellen, for her flightiness, untidiness, and Muggle lineage. Both Orford and his daughter blamed Ellen for Dolores's brother's lack of magical ability, with the result that when Dolores was fifteen, the family split down the middle, Orford and Dolores remaining together, and Ellen vanishing back into the Muggle world with her son. Dolores never saw her mother or brother again, never spoke of either of them, and henceforth pretended to all she met that she was a pure blood."

So she lied about her past from an early age and wasn't pure blood at all. She could, perhaps, still have been a relation, but it is not once mentioned in the full article while her tendency to lie about her ancestry is.

More from the article:

> "Nasty things tended to happen to people who asked about Orford, or anything that Dolores did not like talking about, and people who wanted to remain on her good side pretended to believe her version of her ancestry."